# f# split html by tags

Tags: html, string, parsing, f#, split

I would like to parse an HTML document and print each of the paragraphs to a log file as an individual entry.  So far I have:

```
let parseTextFile (path) =
        let fileText = File.ReadAllText(path)
        fileText.Split('<p>') |> Seq.iter (fun m -> logEmail(m))
```

But unfortunately for me string.Split does not do what I want here, it seems to exist to split a string by a single character delimiter.  How can I split the file up using something more than a single character, it may be nice to have something more than just <p> as well because with just that I will have a </p> at the end of the paragraph.  With a regex or some sort of complex matcher I could more specifically pick out everything between <p> tags.

Comment: Take a look at this overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wmeyer said, you need to use a different overload of the `.Split()` method on strings. In fact, the code you posted won't even compile because `'<p>'` is not a string literal -- you need to use `"<p>"` instead (single quotes are for character literals).

Here's how to use the correct overload of `.Split()`:

```
open System.IO

let parseTextFile path =
    let fileText = File.ReadAllText path
    fileText.Split ([| "<p>"; |], System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    |> Seq.iter logEmail
```

For a quick test in F# Interactive:

```
> "First paragraph<p>Second paragraph.<p><p>Third paragraph.<p>"
   .Split ([| "<p>"; |], System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);;
val it : string [] =
  [|"First paragraph"; "Second paragraph."; "Third paragraph."|]
```

Finally, as @ntr said -- you're much, **much** better off using a library like the HTML Agility Pack for parsing HTML. Their parsers are very robust and will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Try using specific libraries for parsing html, for example [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).